# I can not parse nested structure in Elm

Tags: elm

I am struggling to get elements from complex structure in Elm.

here is the type.

```
type alias Model =
    { key : Nav.Key
    , page : Page
    , tag : List Tag
    }

type alias Tag =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , article : List Article
    }

type alias Article =
    { id : Int
    , image_url : String
    , video_url : String
    , title : String
    , description : String
    }
```

As you can see, there is list of Article in list of Tag.

What I want to do is to access to "title" field and display it.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. What about it confuses you?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering!

I guess model.tagArticle must not be list here?
I just don't know how I can change model.tagArticle to record.

Comment: It is, but `model.tagArticle.articleTag` is treating it as a record, not a list, as the error message says. I don't think you'll want to change `model.tagArticle` to a record, but rather you should just treat it as a list. But then I don't really understand your model (`articleTag` and `tagArticle` aren't particularly descriptive names), so I don't know what to recommend.

Comment: I actually want `model.tagArticle` to be record.
because `model.tagArticle` has only one length of list.
(sorry... name of the model is pretty complicated...)

how do you convert `model.tagArticle` into record?

Comment: Or, This data structure is list of list (there is a list inside of list).
How do you get element from nested list?

Comment: Why is it modeled as a list if it's not actually a list? For the model itself you can just remove `List` from the type, but of course that will have consequences elsewhere.

Comment: There's no magic to nested lists. You'll just have to treat it as a list within a list. Use pattern matching, nested applications of `List.map`, or `List.concat` to merge a list of lists to a single list.

Comment: I don't know how to do nested lists... this is what i am trying to do.
`(List.map(\articles -> List.map(\article -> div [] [ li [] [ text "aaaaaa" ] ])articles) model.tagArticle)`.

but apparently you can't use List.map inside of List.map.
```
This `map` call produces:

    List #(List (Html msg))#

But `ul` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    List #(Html msg)#
```
Do you have any ideas??

Comment: You can use `List.map` inside `List.map`—as the error tells you, the issue isn't that you can't do that, but that the result of doing that is a list of lists, not just a list. If you want to combine all of those lists, use [`List.concatMap`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/List#concatMap) for the outer map, to tell it to combine the child lists.

Comment: @tonteki That depends on what you want to accomplish. What's the output you want from it? If you can update your question with an example of what you want, it might be possible to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @glennsl
Thank you so much!
I just updated my question. What I want to do is to access to title field (inner list) and display it to Elm HTML. Is this clear enough??

Comment: No, because there might not be just one title field. It's in a list of lists, so at the very least you have to deal with the possibility that there are many title fields, or none at all, and probably also the significance of there being many articles in a tag. If this isn't actually a possibility, then the model shouldn't have nested lists.

Comment: You should get the model right first, then deal with all the possibilities that the model presents. The model as it is now suggests a much more complex presentation. If you deliberately want a simplified view of it, you should explicitly say so. But you still have to deal with all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to render out all the `title`s of all the `Article`s for each `Tag`. The problem is, you end up in nested `List`s. Now, there is probably a better way to model your data that avoids deeply nesting product types in product types, and you might want to try using more descriptive names for record fields, but overlooking that, we'll just address the issue you raised. Here `List.concat` and `List.concatMap` are your friends.

I believe you are after something like this:

```
module Whatever exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html, div, text)


type alias Model =
    { key : Nav.Key
    , page : Page
    , tag : List Tag
    }


type alias Tag =
    { id : Int
    , name : String
    , article : List Article
    }


type alias Article =
    { id : Int
    , image_url : String
    , video_url : String
    , title : String
    , description : String
    }


view : Model -> Html msg
view model =
    let
        titles =
            model.tag                  -- List Tag
                |> List.map .article   -- List Tag -> List (List Article)
                |> List.concat         -- List (List Article) -> List (Article)
                |> List.map .title     -- List Article -> List String
    in
    div
        []
        (titles |> List.map text)
```

`List.concat` is what does the trick there. It removes one level of nesting, so you go from a `List (List a)` to a `List a`.

You see above that after flattening the nested lists we then `List.map` over the flattened list one more time to get the list of `title`. This situation where you want to flatten a nested list in order to continue mapping/processing the contents of the list is common enough that the `List` module comes with a handy function called `concatMap` which does the flattening and mapping in one go. So the following is equivalent to the solution above.

```
view : Model -> Html msg
view model =
    let
        titles =
            model.tag |> List.concatMap (.article >> List.map .title)
    in
    div
        []
        (titles |> List.map text)
```

I hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to show the title of each article on the screen, instead of the title of a specific article.

In this case, you can use `List.map` to render the tags and their articles recursively.

Below is the rendered output:

```html
<div style="margin: 1em">
  <h1>Nested Structure Demo in Elm</h1>
  <div>
    <div style="margin: 1em">
      <h2>Tag: Elm</h2>
      <div>
        <div style="margin: 1em">
          <h3>Article: Using type alias for custom data type</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 1em">
          <h3>Article: TEA: The Elm Architecture</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 1em">
      <h2>Tag: TypeScript</h2>
      <div>
        <div style="margin: 1em">
          <h3>Article: Custom Type in Typescript</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 1em">
          <h3>Article: Unions and Intersection Types</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the example Demo.elm:

```elm
module Demo exposing (..)

import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        }


type alias Model =
    { tags : List Tag
    }


type alias Tag =
    { name : String
    , articles : List Article
    }


type alias Article =
    { title : String
    }


init : Model
init =
    { tags =
        [ { name = "Elm"
          , articles =
                [ { title = "Using type alias for custom data type" }
                , { title = "TEA: The Elm Architecture" }
                ]
          }
        , { name = "TypeScript"
          , articles =
                [ { title = "Custom Type in Typescript" }
                , { title = "Unions and Intersection Types" }
                ]
          }
        ]
    }


type Msg
    = Msg


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update _ model =
    model


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [ margin ]
        [ h1 [] [ text "Nested Structure Demo in Elm" ]
        , div [] (List.map viewTag model.tags)
        ]


viewTag : Tag -> Html Msg
viewTag tag =
    div [ margin ]
        [ h2 [] [ text "Tag: ", text tag.name ]
        , div [] (List.map viewArticle tag.articles)
        ]


viewArticle : Article -> Html Msg
viewArticle article =
    div [ margin ]
        [ h3 [] [ text "Article: ", text article.title ]
        ]


margin : Attribute msg
margin =
    style "margin" "1em"
```

Comment: The different between my version and Derrick's is: I preserved the hierarchy structure of the articles under the tags (not flatten them into a 1d array)

Comment: I skipped irrelevant fields in the type aliases